# In-game ping went up after upgrading internet speed

Tags: technical-issues, dota-2

I have a problem with my online In-game ping.
I had an ISP that gave me 3 Mbits/s and my ping was about 80 ms, then I changed my ISP and got more speed (5Mbit/s) but that made my ping went up, now I'm on 140 ms. What's the problem and how can I make my ping go down?

By the way, I'm using a new wifi router, could that be the problem? I didn't test it with an ethernet cable, because my computer is too far from the ISP modem. Help please!

Comment: The wifi could be in cause and also the new isp dns servers might not be, yet, giving you the best route to your game's server. Hard to know exactly, under windows, using [tracert](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/162326) [ip of the game's server] would give you an idea of where to slowest point is.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Any idea how can i low my ping without the help of the ISP?

Comment: You first got to know where to slowest point is. Without that information, it is pointless to try to lower your ping in a way that won't change it. If it is between your pc and your router, you'll be able to do something. If it is between your router and the game's server, only your isp might be able to help, if the slowest point is their dns server.

Comment: A ton of factors can cause this.

Exchange congestion, network availability, ISP Throttling, DNS Cache congestion and even having your account at your ISP established as a low-priority account, Packet loss (which means your account should return to a higher speed during late hours of the night when it's not peak time). In South Africa, this is a few common reasons your situation happens to us, thanks to Hellkom (Telkom). I suggest phoning both your new ISP and your telecommunications provider and find out what gives

Comment: To know which ip to traceroute to, check [valve's ip list](http://bgp.he.net/AS32590#_prefixes), taken from [this thread](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=63582)

Answer (score 2):

Your old isp had better routes through Dota servers. You can't actually say "I upgraded my internet speed by changing isp", because there are many factors that you should consider when saying that, one of them being speed to get [where].

You can double your download rate from [somewhere], while totally loosing connectivity towards [somewhere else] -> for example Dota servers.

When changing isp you need to consider your location, peering provided, what you use the most.

You asked: @JonathanDrapeau Any idea how can i low my ping without the help of the ISP?

Yes, you can, but requires a bit of knowledge. If you know a better route to your destination (Dota servers) you can set it manually (I presume you have windows so this may help https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_addstaticroute.mspx?mfr=true - did not actually try it, I set my routes on my router). Also you can use a proxy or use tunneling software, but I recommend against it if you don't really know what you are doing.

One last edit...

1. 140 is not such a bad ping unless you are playing in some high end games. For moderate games is pretty decent.
2. Yes, it may be your  wireless too. Switching to eth would be better. And about the distance... come on, it takes you 10 min to make a cable, and that includes washing your hands after :).